# Offset curves from Linestring to Polygon using PostGIS/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, width, polygon, postgis, multilinestring

I have street (linestring) and building (polygon) tables in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database (PostGIS 2.2) on Windows 7 (x64) machine like this.

[image: street_with_buildings]

I am trying to compute the width of street by drawing offset curves around street. The idea is to draw parallel lines (offset curves) around street and then use `ST_Distance()` to compute the disctance between them (width). Using following query, I could draw parallel lines on both sides of street using PostGIS function `ST_OffsetCurve()`. Both tables make use of EPSG:3044.

```
SELECT 
f.gid,
ST_Union(
    ST_OffsetCurve(ST_LineMerge(f.geom), 6.0, 'quad_segs=4 join=round'),
    ST_OffsetCurve(ST_LineMerge(f.geom), -6.0, 'quad_segs=4 join=round')
    ) as track
FROM
street f;
```

Above query looks like this:

[image]

So far, these offset curves are at the fixed distance of 6 meters from street. For each street, I would like to draw these offset curves along buiding facades (edge of polygon facing the street). Can someone help me how to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it using the parallel lines method or how about getting the distance from the centreline to the closest point for the buildings either side?

Comment: Well, +1 for your suggestion! This was just an idea somehow. There could be more better and more efficient approach to do this (for example suggested by you). Being a newbie, I ended up with this way to compute width. Nevertheless, computing the distance to either side of street would also be fine.

Comment: Perhaps using the distance between the two closest points (either side of road) based on searching from the centroid of each line... though would likely need a bit of experimentation.

Comment: If you meant the closest point on polygon from the street then it could work but using ST_ClosestPoint() would probably not project closest points perpendicularly over polygons. Just a comment though it seems like a good idea.